# QBE query not retrieving expected results

Tags: marklogic

I'm using [Query By Example (QBE)](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/qbe) to try and retrieve certain entries from the ML database. I'm attempting to retrieve entries that match all of the criteria in the query. Here is the query I'm currently using:

```
{
  "$query": {
    "$and": [
      {
        "data": {
          "name": "Name",
          "active": true,
          "nestedProperty": {
            "prop1": "Value 1",
            "prop2": "Value 2",
            "prop3": 50
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, it's not returning what I expected. I think it's just returning anything that matches any of the properties. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Can you provide data sample your searching on? This way impossible to tell.

Comment: Can you provide a data sample? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a data sample? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the false alarm - turns out there was code on the server side that was mapping one of the properties to a different value. The query actually did work, I just had to account for the change.